# How to implement `Search box` through `props items` using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, search-box

I want to implement search box from my set of `props` data .
I tried to follow this article https://dev.to/iam_timsmith/lets-build-a-search-bar-in-react-120j but i guess i m doing some silly mistakes.
any help to correct my mistake would be helpful for me.

//allbook.js

```
    class AllBook extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search : ""
        }

    }
    updateSearch(e){
        this.setState({search: e.target.value.substr(0, 20)});
    }

    render(){
        let filteredBooks = this.props.posts.filter(
            (posts) => {
                return posts.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            }
        );
        return(
            <div>
                {Object.keys(filteredBooks).length !== 0 ?  <h1 className="post-heading">All books</h1> : <h1 className="post-heading">No Books available</h1>}  {/*To check if array is empty or not*/}


                {Object.keys(filteredBooks).length !== 0 ?
                <input className="post-heading" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/> : ""}

                {/*Arrow function to map each added object*/}
                {filteredBooks.map((post) =>(

                    <div key={post.id}>

                        {post.editing ? <EditComponent post={post} key={post.id}/> :
                            <Post key={post.id} post={post}/>}
                    </div>
                ))}

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        posts: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllBook);
```

Comment: Can you add this to codeSend box or JSFiddle ??

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma thank you for your answer. but i just got this work around . although thank you

Comment: @TanmoySarkar just created a sandbox that could be of some help to you. It looks like you got mostly everything covered though :)

Answer (score 2):

Your updated code seems to be pretty close. I think you might experience a problem with using `indexOf()` though, since that will only find the index of a single-character within a string (title). This would not be good for multi-character searches (like full-words).

Try using `.includes()` instead so that you can at least search against complete words and titles. It's essentially a better version of `.indexOf()`

See sandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-currying-3zpvk

### Working code:

```
    class AllBook extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search : ""
        }

    }
    updateSearch(e){
        this.setState({search: e.target.value.substr(0, 20)});
    }

    render(){
        let filteredBooks = this.props.posts.filter(
            (posts) => {
                return posts.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase());
            }
        );
        return(
            <div>
                {Object.keys(filteredBooks).length !== 0 ?  <h1 className="post-heading">All books</h1> : <h1 className="post-heading">No Books available</h1>}  {/*To check if array is empty or not*/}


                {Object.keys(filteredBooks).length !== 0 ?
                <input className="post-heading" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/> : ""}

                {/*Arrow function to map each added object*/}
                {filteredBooks.map((post) =>(

                    <div key={post.id}>

                        {post.editing ? <EditComponent post={post} key={post.id}/> :
                            <Post key={post.id} post={post}/>}
                    </div>
                ))}

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        posts: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllBook);
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated code which is workable react search.